# Creating a CSS form that's horizontal using CSS not tables with boxes above text

Tags: html, css, forms, css-tables

I'm trying to create a table like the pic I made below do I div everything?

[image]

Comment: Please try to do some research next time, or show the code that you already tried.  To me this reads: please code this for me.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
<div style="font-size: 25px">
    Contant Information</div>
<div style="border-bottom: 1px black dashed;width:55%">
</div>
<ul style="padding-left: 0px">
    <div style="margin-top: 4px; display: inline-block">
        First Name</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 200px">
        Last Name</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 200px">
        Phone Number</div>
    <br><input><input style="margin-left: 113px"><input style="margin-left: 113px"></ul>
<div style="border-bottom: 1px black dashed; margin-top: 5px;width:55%">
</div>
<ul style="font-size: 20px">
    Desired Vehicle</ul>
<div style="border-bottom: 1px black dashed; margin-top: 5px;width:55%">
</div>
<ul style="padding-left: 0px">
    <div style="margin-top: 4px; display: inline-block">
        Year</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 238px">
        Make</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 230px">
        Model</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 225px">
        Price Range</div>
    <br><input><input style="margin-left: 113px"><input style="margin-left: 113px"><input style="margin-left: 113px"></ul>
<div style="border-bottom: 1px black dashed; margin-top: 5px;width:55%">
</div>
<ul style="padding-left: 0px; font-size: 17px">
    <div>
        List any other features you would like the vehicle to include</div>
    <textarea style="width: 600px; height: 120px"></textarea></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern. Don't forget to clear your floats.

```
<div class="contact">
<ul>
    <li><label>First Name</label><input type="text" /></li>
    <li><label>Last Name</label><input type="text" /></li>
    ... etc ...
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

label {
     display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the elements in a containing div that has the width you want, you shouldn't need to put each row in its own div. You could make divs for the rows with more than one input element, and then set the input elements to

```
display:inline-block;
```

so that they will line up horizontally if their containing div is large enough to hold them inline, but you can set widths for them like block-level elements. You can also put top and bottom borders on those divs to get the dividing lines you have in the image you posted.

Making inputs behave like block elements can be a little weird - you could also try this method, using the CSS3 box-sizing property, to style them:

http://craveytrain.com/posts/making-inputs-behave.